# Stub interface with generic methods that take predicates

Tags: c#, lambda, microsoft-fakes

I am really struggling with getting this to work. I have a generic repository pattern and I need to stub the repository interface using Microsoft Fakes.

```
public interface IDataAccess<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    T FindById(long id);
    T FindById(string id);
    T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    IEnumerable<T> FindAll();
    IEnumerable<T> FindMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);
    IQueryable<T> FindIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties);
}
```

trying to create a stub for

```
IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);
IQueryable<T> FindIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties);
```

and in my test..

```
IDataAccess<EnterprisePermissionSet> dataAccess = new HG.Fus.Authentication.Data.Fakes.
            StubIDataAccess<EnterprisePermissionSet>()
        {
            FindIncludingExpressionOfFuncOfT0ObjectArray = () => { };
        };
```

I just have no clue how to construct this stub,

Comment: You have to simulate the behavior which you are looking for inside the `{ }`

Comment: That's what I was doing at first but keep getting an error that I cannot convert source type 'Lambda Expression' to target type 'IQueryable<EnterprisePermissionSet>'

Comment: ok, read my answer, I show the way to stub those methods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MsFakes` uses code generation to replace to fake methods, create stubs and etc...
To replace a particular method you have to set new method(`Action` or `Func` based on the method signature) which will receive any call to this particular method.

The signature of the method you wish to fake is:

```
IQueryable<T> FindIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties);
```

Based on this signature you have to set a `Func` which gets an array of `Expression<Func<T, object>>` and returns `IQueryable<T>`.
The following snippet shows a simple example to replace the above method:

```
fakeDataAccess.FindIncludingExpressionOfFuncOfT0ObjectArray = expressions =>
{
   // here you can create the logic / fill the return value and etc...
   return new List<EnterprisePermissionSet>().AsQueryable(); \\this example is match your T
};
```

The easiest way to simulate `IQueryable<T>` is to return a collection through `AsQueryable()`, another way is to use `EnumerableQuery` class.

Here is the example to replace: `IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);`

```
fakeDataAccess.FindExpressionOfFuncOfT0BooleanExpressionOfFuncOfT0ObjectArray =
(expression, expressions) =>
     {
          // here you can create the logic / fill the return value and etc...
          return new List<EnterprisePermissionSet>().AsQueryable();
     };
```